# Validation Rule for editing Accounts with a specific Record Type given to System Administrators and 2 specific Users

Tags: validation-rule

We have created a new Record Type for Accounts called "Brand". I am trying to set it up to where only System Administrators and 2 other specific Users can edit Accounts with the "Brand" Record Type. Below is the formula I am trying to use but I keep getting syntax errors and am stumped:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Including the error message you're getting (verbaitm, don't try to paraphrase it) is always helpful. Also, including the code/formula as text rather than a screenshot is preferred (easier to copy/paste to make simple corrections in answers).

Comment: That said, this looks like a simple structural issue to me. You only have two open parenthesis but have 4 close parenthesis. Using `AND()` and `OR()` means that everything undergoing a particular operation must appear in between the open and close parenthesis.

Comment: This would probably be better as a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5), but failing that, you don't want nor need an `OR()` here. Remember than validation rules prevent changes to records when they evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @DerekF - Here is my formula: AND(
OR(
RecordType.Name ="Brand"
),
$User.Id <> '0054V00000F9RBbQAN',
$User.Id <> '0054V00000G8He8QAF'
)
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'
)) The error I am getting says Error: Syntax error. Extra $Profile.Name

Comment: avoid hardcoded Ids in formulas as they are not transparent to the admin (you have other options including username, federationId, alias, nickname  or, at least add comments to the formula

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try as below. You need to use ISNEW() to restrict edit access. I don't know who downgraded your question but not many folks know about ISNEW(). You just need to update Profile.Name conditions in the below formula

```
AND( 
    NOT(ISNEW()), 
    RecordType.Name = 'Brand', 
    OR(
        ($Profile.Name = 'Clone SysAdmin'),
        ($Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
    )
)
```